# LXDE autostart procedure failed : file not found

Tags: lxde

I'm trying to start Libreoffice impress automatically once my raspberry pi has started up.

I created: 
.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart:

```
sudo libreoffice -show /home/pi/test.odp
```

When I execute the command in a terminal, all works fine. However the autostart doesn't seem to work at boot. Libreoffice starts, but then says it can't find the file...

Comment: The content of the file : sudo libreoffice -show /home/pi/test.odp

Comment: Sorry -- didn't see that before.  It's not a relative path, so that's not the problem.  Why do you need `sudo` there?

Comment: Sorry the sudo was left of an experiment to solve the issue...

Comment: Note that that won't run at *boot*, it will run after you log in.

Comment: Baby I know, desktop and all is visible. Libreoffice starts,  but then says it can't find the file.

Comment: Just checking -- you use the phrase "the autostart doesn't seem to work *at boot*" above.

Comment: Hmm -- does it say it cannot find that file specifically?  As in "Cannot find /home/pi/test.odp"?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sc/hsstbraaygenk0c/AADV6NZIL_nk5G_Bs8PJy9dTa -> screenshot

Comment: This is a really dumb question but sometimes things happen like this so it doesn't hurt to ask: did you double check to make sure there is a file in the pi folder called "test.odp" and that it opens normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally cracked down and reinstalled the latest raspbian on the SD card. Now all the problems are gone...

Thanks for the support! It was a weird issue ...